# Send location option with CURL in asterisk dialplan

Tags: curl, redirect, post, asterisk

How can i send the `--location` option to follow redirects with a http post with CURL in an asterisk dialplan equivalent to
`curl -L --data "FirstNme=John&LastName=Doe&PhoneNumber=8005551212" https://www.example.com`

I tried to do

```
same => n,Set(CURLOPT(location))
same => n,Set(response=${CURL(https://www.example.com,FirstNme=John&LastName=Doe&PhoneNumber=8005551212)})
```

and

```
same => n,Set(response=${CURL(https://www.example.com,-L --data "FirstNme=John&LastName=Doe&PhoneNumber=8005551212")})
```

and it did't work.

how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CURLOPT now has `followlocation` and `maxredirs` parameters

> CURLOPT() Synopsis
>
> Sets various options for future invocations of CURL. Description
>
> Options may be set globally or per channel. Per-channel settings will
> override global settings. Only HTTP headers are added instead of
> overriding Syntax
>
> CURLOPT(key)
>
> Arguments
>
> - key
>
>   - cookie - A cookie to send with the request. Multiple cookies are supported.
>   - conntimeout - Number of seconds to wait for a connection to succeed
>   - dnstimeout - Number of seconds to wait for DNS to be resolved
>   - **followlocation - Whether or not to follow HTTP 3xx redirects (boolean)**
>   - ftptext - For FTP URIs, force a text transfer (boolean)
>   - ftptimeout - For FTP URIs, number of seconds to wait for a server response
>   - header - Include header information in the result (boolean)
>   - httpheader - Add HTTP header. Multiple calls add multiple headers. Setting of any header will remove the default "Content-Type
>     application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
>   - httptimeout - For HTTP(S) URIs, number of seconds to wait for a server response
>   - **maxredirs - Maximum number of redirects to follow. The default is -1, which allows for unlimited redirects. This only makes
>     sense when followlocation is also set.**
>   - proxy - Hostname or IP address to use as a proxy server
>   - proxytype - Type of proxy
>
>     - http
>     - socks4
>     - socks5
>   - proxyport - Port number of the proxy
>   - proxyuserpwd - A username:password combination to use for authenticating requests through a proxy
>   - referer - Referer URL to use for the request
>   - useragent - UserAgent string to use for the request
>   - userpwd - A username:password to use for authentication when the server response to an initial request indicates a 401 status code.
>   - ssl_verifypeer - Whether to verify the server certificate against a list of known root certificate authorities (boolean).
>   - hashcompat - Assuming the responses will be in key1=value1&key2=value2 format, reformat the response such that it can
>     be used by the HASH function.
>
>     - yes
>     - no
>     - legacy - Also translate + to the space character, in violation of current RFC standards.
>   - failurecodes - A comma separated list of HTTP response codes to be treated as errors

Answer (score 1):

CURLOPT is not variable, it is FUNCTION. It have really limited number of options.

It is opensource, you can add your function into source code(minimal c/c++ experience under linux is required).

```
pro-sip*CLI> core show function CURLOPT 

  -= Info about function 'CURLOPT' =- 

[Synopsis]
Set options for use with the CURL() function

[Description]
  cookie         - Send cookie with request [none]
  conntimeout    - Number of seconds to wait for connection
  dnstimeout     - Number of seconds to wait for DNS response
  ftptext        - For FTP, force a text transfer (boolean)
  ftptimeout     - For FTP, the server response timeout
  header         - Retrieve header information (boolean)
  httptimeout    - Number of seconds to wait for HTTP response
  maxredirs      - Maximum number of redirects to follow
  proxy          - Hostname or IP to use as a proxy
  proxytype      - http, socks4, or socks5
  proxyport      - port number of the proxy
  proxyuserpwd   - A <user>:<pass> to use for authentication
  referer        - Referer URL to use for the request
  useragent      - UserAgent string to use
  userpwd        - A <user>:<pass> to use for authentication
  ssl_verifypeer - Whether to verify the peer certificate (boolean)
  hashcompat     - Result data will be compatible for use with HASH()
                 - if value is "legacy", will translate '+' to ' '


[Syntax]
CURLOPT(<option>)

[Arguments]
Not available

[See Also]
Not available
```

Please not forget, asterisk is PBX, not programming language. You always can use AGI/FastAGI/ARI with your preferred language.

Comment: Is there a way to follow redirects with CURL dialplan function?

Comment: Source code is availible. Sorry, i have no 2-3hr of time to read it just to answer your question. For complex tasks use external control app.